# Existence of a holomorphic map between Riemann surfaces

Tags: riemann-surfaces

Nevanlinna in his book *Analytic functions* seems to state the following (at the very end of Ch. X): For every compact Riemann surface $X$ of genus $g\geq 2$ there is a non-constant holomorphic map $f : X \to Y$ to some hyperelliptic Riemann surface $Y$. How is this proved?

I explain in more detail. Nevanlinna proves the theorem of Picard that there is no non-constant map of the complex plane to a compact Riemann surface of genus $g \geq 2$. The proof begins with the sentence:

> As Picard noticed, it is enough to prove this for a hyperelliptic curve.

And proceeds to prove the theorem for hyperelliptic case.

The corresponding paper of Picard (Acta 11, 1887,
p. 11-12) refers in the relevant place to a private letter of Hurwitz.  It says:

Soit $f(x, y)=0$, la relation que l'on ne suppose pas hyperelliptique, et pour laquelle on a par consequent $g>2$. A l'equation prcedente, le savant geomere associe une relation
$$f_1(x,y_1)=0\quad\mbox{de genre}\quad g=2$$
jouissant des proprietes suivantes: les points de ramification de la fonction algebrique $y_1$ de $x$ sont tous compris parmi les points de ramification de la fonction algebrique $y$ de $x$ (on suppose, pour plus de simplicite, et comme il est permis, que tous les points de ramification de la fonction donnent seulement des cycles de deux racines) et dans le voisinage de tout point analytique $(x,y)$ de fonction $y$, la fonction $y_1$ peut etre consideree comme une fonction uniforme du point $(x,y)$.

Can anyone explain what Picard says here, and why is this correct?

Comment: This is not true:  a general curve $X$ of genus $\geq 2$ has no nontrivial map to a curve of genus $\geq 1$. I couldn't find anything in Nevanlinna's book that resembles this statement.

Comment: @abx: And what about the identity map $X\to X$ ?

Comment: @abx: It is the last paragraph of Chap. 10, the proof of a theorem of Picard. He refers to Picard and Bloch on this, but none of them gives a clear statement, not speaking of a proof.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: the operative word is "general", the identity map is not particularly general :-)

Comment: @ChristianRemling, ah, ok, I'll delete my now-irrelevant comment... :)

Comment: I read Nevanlinna as saying "all of the ideas (for general $X$) are contained in the proof of the hyperelliptic case."

Comment: Hmmm.  Is every Riemann surface $X$ branched covered by a hyperelliptic surface?  This would also give a proof (because the plane is simply connected).

Comment: @SamNead if i'm not mistaken, wouldn't that mean that the corresponding finite extension $K/\mathbb{C}(t)$ of the field of rational functions embeds into a degree 2 extension $\supset \supset \mathbb{C}(t)$ and then the Galois group $K/\mathbb{C}(t)$ should be a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ but the Galois group of a generic finite extension $K/\mathbb{C}(t)$ is  $S_n$ or something.

Comment: Is the theorem of Picard (as stated by Nevanlinna) not stronger than stated above, in that it asserts that there are no nonconstant *finitely punctured* holomorphic planes in X, not just no nonconstant holomorphic planes?

Comment: Ok, even if it were true that all X have a hyperelliptic branched cover, we would not yet have a proof.  The simple conectivity of $\mathbb{C}$ means it lifts to *covers*, not to *branched covers*.  Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what Picard says, translated in modern algebraic geometry language:

You have a curve $X$ with a map $\pi :X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$.
Assume for simplicity that for each $z\in \mathbb{P}^1$, $\pi ^{-1}(z)$ contains at most one  ramification point, with ramification index 2. Choose 6 branch points of $\pi $, and let $\rho :C\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ be the double covering branched at these 6 points (so $g(C)=2$). Now consider the fiber product $X\times _{\mathbb{P}^1}C$. It has a node over each of the 6 branch points of $\rho$; take its normalization, say $\tilde{X} $. Now $\tilde{\rho }:\tilde{X} \rightarrow X $ is étale (that is, analytically, a local isomorphism), and we have a (nontrivial) map $\tilde{X}\rightarrow  C$.

Comment: Could you please extend your explanation a bit? Suppose $X$ receives a non-constant holomorphic map from the complex pane. Why $\tilde{X}$ does?

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand your question. $X$ has genus $\geq 2$, there is no non-constant holomorphic map from the complex plane to $X$.

Comment: Correct. But Picard used this construction to PROVE this fact, that there is no map from C to a curve of genus >2. How exactly did he reduce the proof of this theorem to hyperelliptic case?

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I didn't pay attention to this. Well, suppose you have a nontrivial map $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow X$; using the notation in my previous comment, since $\tilde{\rho} $ is étale, this map lifts to $\tilde{X} $, then by projection to $C$ gives a nontrivial map $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow C$.

Comment: If we have a map $\mathbb C\to X$, we can also just lift it to the universal cover of $X$ (=$D$ if $g(X)\ge 2$) to obtain a bounded entire function.

Comment: @Christian Remling: yes, of course. But the question is to understand how Picard (or Nevanlinna?) wanted to proceed.

Comment: @Christian Remling: we are discussing Picard's paper of 1887; it was published long before the general uniformization theorem was proved, and before the universal cover was defined.